# Getting HttpMessageNotReadableException exception when using the RestTemplate to get a JSON object

Tags: java, spring, api, resttemplate

So i'm working on a REST client that consumes a REST API to get a json object using the Spring RestTemplate. I'm setting the necessary headers with the api key. I keep getting this error when I fires the request.

```
Could not read document: Can not construct instance of io.sample.poynt.client.domain.PoyntBusinessDetails$Address: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4ee48093; line: 1, column: 13] (through reference chain: io.sample.poynt.client.domain.PoyntBusinessDetails["address"])
```

code snippet :

```
 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.set(API_VERSION_HEADER, "1.2");
    headers.set(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, apiToken);
    HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
    ResponseEntity<PoyntBusinessDetails> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            poyntCloudBusinessUrl+businessId, HttpMethod.GET, entity, PoyntBusinessDetails.class);
```

PoyntBusinessDetails class:

```
public class PoyntBusinessDetails {

private String mockProcessor;
private String createdDate;
private String updatedDate;
private String activatedDate;
private String status;
private String type;
private Attribute attribute;
private Address address;
private Phone phone;
private String acquirer;
private String processor;
private String externalMerchantId;
private String legalName;
private String businessUrl;
private String emailAddress;
private String doingBusinessAs;
private String industryType;
private String mcc;
private String sic;
private String timezone;
private String id;

 public PoyntBusinessDetails() {
}

// getters and setters
}

private class Address {

    // fields

    // getters and setters
}

private class Attribute {

    // fields

    // getters and setters
}


private class Phone {

    // fields
    // getters and setters
 }

}
```

So here i'm attaching the sample request from the API end point. (which i get from the postman)

```
{
"address": {
   //fields
},
"mockProcessor": false,
"status": "ACTIVATED",
"type": "MERCHANT",
"activeSince": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z",
"createdAt": "2019-02-04T21:30:16Z",
"updatedAt": "2019-02-19T15:45:52Z",
"attributes": {
    //fields
},
"phone": {
    //fields
},
"acquirer": "xxxx",
"processor": "xxxx",
"externalMerchantId": "xxxx",
"legalName": "OLYMPUS",
"businessUrl": " www.xxxx.com",
"emailAddress": "accounting@xxxx.com",
"doingBusinessAs": "OLYMPUS",
"industryType": "Retail",
"mcc": "5999",
"sic": "5999",
"timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
"id": "xxxx"
}
```

What am i missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: `Address`, `Attribute`,`Phone` make them public classes, if they are private how they can be instantiated from another class? properties should be private with getters and setters but not classes

Comment: Also, your PoyntBusinessDetails.java model and Response should match perfectly. Otherwise, use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on top of your PoyntBusinessDetails.java